# Can't update data in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

Goal:
Having two buttons that should be enable to add or delete data from datagridview. The changes should be make in real time so you should be see the new result.

Problem:
Having problem to display the new result after I have used button add functionality because the result won't display in real time. In order to view the result I have to close and reopen the application in order to view the new result.

Please remember that I don't use a database.

I'm using class table and then I connect the table to the datagridview's datasource.

```
      DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("a");
        table.Columns.Add("b");

        foreach (var a in myManagerProduct.GetAllProductList())
        {

                DataRow row;
                row = table.NewRow();

                row["a"] = a._articleNumber;
                row["b"] = a._name;
                dgridStock.Rows.Add(row);

                table.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        dgridStock.DataSource = table;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code snippet to add new row to the grid.

```
    DataView dv = ((dgridStock.BindingContext[dgridStock.DataSource] as CurrencyManager).List as DataView);
    DataRowView rowView = dv.AddNew();
    rowView["a"] = a._articleNumber;
    rowView["b"] = a._name;
    rowView.EndEdit();
```

And make sure `dgridStock.DataSource = table;` is set only once. After that every addition shouldn't refresh the DataSource property.

Comment: I tried your solution but it only add a new row with a copy of the latest data from thhe gridview and you can't see the new data unless you close and activate the winform.

Comment: Try following two methods after you add a row. 'dgridStock.Invalidate or dgridStock.Refresh'

Answer (score 0):

As Sanjeevakumar Hiremath said, don't forget EndEdit() command for row or DataTable in general. After finishing all the operations about inserting, updating and deleting data, call DataGridView.Refresh().

Comment: this would have gone well as a comment